# How to remove spaces that is inserted to fill a page

Tags: spacing, ieeetran, ieee-style, biography

I am using IEEEtran template for a journal transaction. I am required to insert authors biographies at the end. But when I insert them, they do not appear next to each other. Instead, a large space is inserted between them. How to remove this space?

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %optional
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm} % optional

\begin{document}
    \title{{Paper}}

    \author{Author}

    \maketitle

    \section{Section} 

%bios
\begin{IEEEbiography}{First Author} Some text here.\end{IEEEbiography}

\begin{IEEEbiography}{Second Author} some text here.
\end{IEEEbiography} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also add \vfill or \vspace*{\fill} after the last biography.  However, IEEE probably set it up this way for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Just give `\vskip 0pt plus -1fil` between the `IEEEbiography` environments. If you want them too closely, adjust 0pt to `-2\baselineskip`.

[image]

```
\begin{IEEEbiography}{First Author} Some text here. \end{IEEEbiography}
\vskip 0pt plus -1fil

\begin{IEEEbiography}{Second Author} Some text here. 
\end{IEEEbiography}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide the answer (the full command).

Comment: `\vskip 0pt plus -1fil`

Comment: Where to add this line? adding it between the two bios made no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I could find is adding this at the preamble:

```
\usepackage{flushend}
```